# How to recompile OpenCV with text.hpp (optional modules)?

Tags: c++, opencv, compiler-errors

So i'm trying to build [the demo program for text detection](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/samples/textdetection.cpp), and CMake is complaining that "text.hpp" doesn't exist. I looked it up and turns out it only exists in [the optional modules](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib). **How do I recompile OpenCV with these modules without blowing up everything?**

Edit: I'm using Ubuntu, and I compile programs using CMake from the command line.

Edit 2: I tried running `sudo make uninstall`, cloning both of the repos (main and modules) and then [following the instructions to build with those modules](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html), but CMake still reports that text.hpp doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I set OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH to `"<project_dir>/opencv_contrib"`, forgetting to put the `/modules` at the end... sorry everyone

Answer (score 1):

The following instruction describes how to build OpenCV 3.4.0 as well as the extra modules from the scratch. We assume to use Visual Studio 2017 15.5 and CMake 3.10.0-rc1. The following commands are executed on Git bash in Windows. `<project_dir>` denotes the directory that resides the cloned repositories.

1. Clone the repositories

   ```
   $ cd <project_dir>  
   $ git clone git@github.com:opencv/opencv.git  
   $ cd opencv  
   $ git checkout tags/3.4.0

   $ cd <project_dir>
   $ git clone git@github.com:opencv/opencv_contrib.git
   $ cd opencv_contrib
   $ git checkout tags/3.4.0
   ```
2. Configure OpenCV with the extra modules

   ```
   $ cd <project_dir>/opencv
   $ mkdir build && cd build
   $ cmake \
   -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH="<project_dir>/opencv_contrib/modules" \
   -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ..
   ```
3. Build and install the library. The built libraries and headers would be installed in  `<project_dir>/opencv/build/install`.

   ```
   $ cmake --build . --config Release --target INSTALL
   ```
4. It seems the sample that you mentioned is not built by default. Let's build it. First create the new project directory and copy the necessary files.

   ```
   $ cd <project_dir>
   $ mkdir opencv_text_samples && cd opencv_text_samples
   $ cp <project_dir>/opencv_contrib/modules/text/samples/* .
   ```
5. Create a CMakeLists.txt as

   ```
   $ cat CMakeLists.txt
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
   project(opencv_text_samples)
   find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
   add_executable(textdetection textdetection.cpp)
   target_link_libraries(textdetection ${OpenCV_LIBS})
   ```
6. Build the project. The OpenCV's install directory must be specified in `OpenCV_DIR`.

   ```
   $ mkdir build && cd build
   $ cmake \
   -D OpenCV_DIR="<project_dir>/opencv/build/install" \
   -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ..
   ```
7. Copy the necessary dlls and dependencies. Done!

   ```
   $ cp <project_dir>/opencv/build/install/x64/vc15/bin/* .
   $ cp <project_dir>/opencv_contrib/*.xml .
   $ ./textdetection ../../scenetext_word01.jpg
   ```

Comment: 1. I already have OpenCV compiled, I'm not building from scratch. Do I need to delete stuff before recompiling? 2. I'm not using Visual Studio, I'm using CMake from the command line to compile my programs. 3. I'm also using Ubuntu but looks like that doesn't change much.